# installing problem of chrome in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome

I am unable to install chrome. I am getting an error saying

```
dpkg: error processing archive /Absolute/Path/to/chrome.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you edit the question by including the command you used to install chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the Chrome .deb file using a web browser, the location of the Chrome .deb file that you downloaded is saved in the download history of your web browser. Open Files file browser and browse to the directory that contains the Chrome .deb file that you downloaded and then double-click that .deb file to open it for installation in Ubuntu Software. Ubuntu Software will prompt you to authenticate with your user password in order to install Chrome.